# Way to get Visa to UK any faster?

Tags: visas

I have already sent the visa application off the the hub in NYC for a visa to the UK and didn't realize I had to put a rush on it when I originally applied. I leave for Australia shortly and want to know is there anyway to contact anyone to speed up the process, I am happy to go in person to NYC but it seems that is not doable, and I can not find any phone number to call either?  I am a US citizen and applied that way, but also an Australian citizen..

Comment: Why did you apply for a visa when you could travel visa free on either your American or Australian passport? Is it an ordinary visit? See the answer to this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/how-to-expedite-a-uk-visa-application

Comment: Contact the Visa Facilitation Service where you submitted the application and find out if they offer a way to "promote" your application to high priority. This opportunity is offered to end-users on a country-by-country basis.

Comment: An example is the "User Pay Services" page on the VFS India site. From personal experience I can say that "promoting" an application may or may not have an effect; you cannot force them to make a decision if they are not ready to make one. For complex applications, they will take the money and continue with whatever they were doing so promoting your application may not be helpful.

Comment: If you are a US or Australian citizen, you need no visa to visit the UK. Why have you applied for one at all?